# Suitable name for book of prophecies, book of riddles

Tags: names, written-material

I have used some prophecies and riddles in my stories. All of them were written into books placed in library called *Old world diary*.

That book should have name - to it could be quoted as source of knowledge of prophecies and riddles. But I would not like to call it only Book of prophecies or Book of riddles.

---

Examples:

*Breeding*:

> Two become one, one becomes two and all begin again.

*The Guardian*:

> One has to die to else one can be born.
>   And daughter gains gift from mother.

*Defeating of Shining ones*:

> They are not alive for they are not in love with the life.
>   They are not dead for they are afraid of the death.
>   What a surprise to see them to welcome the life and to put the death to flight.
>   To bring them from space somewhere between is only one way to win.
>   To break the magic field what is holding them within.

*Ascension to Shining ones*:

> Magic is time you count.
>   Magic is force that keeps you on the earth.
>   Magic is all you can see and touch.
>   When she is all of that, then what are you?

Comment: This question is quite opinion based and hard to answer so don't be surprised if it is closed.

Comment: This seems like a decision the worldbuilder should make about his/her world. If you are really having trouble there are random name generators all over the web that are free to use.

Answer (score 1):

With these books you have a few options:

1) Named after something else in your world. A famous prophetess or maybe a city that prophecies were made in.

2) Named for a feature if the book. If a prophecy predicts Armageddon then the book could be called Prophecies of Armageddon or if the prophecies name a person they could be the Prophecies on (person's name).

3) Named for something that happened to the book. If the book was declared blasphemous then it may be called the Evil Book or the Book of Sin. Or the book might have been burned The Burnt Book.